# Got Blank issue for get data from /wp-json/v2/post

Tags: rest-api

before I was enabled to get data from my website using Wordpress API V2. I access https://sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts it will return the post with default number per game is 10. then after we add more text on the post, it's seams return nothing, when I try to hit with the postman, it's blank, with body content-length is 0.

I have read so much article and documentation, some post said it because Wordpress did a substring while the return and it will return null if the char more than 2000 char.

Before I can get the data from the postman, there is anybody faces the same issue?

Thank you,
Best Regards.

Comment: So, if you write a post that has more than 2000 characters, the core posts endpoint returns nothing?

Comment: Yes Mate, IDK why like that, the only way I get the data is to made customer API and did a print_r and I know that kind of things is not proper. have you know why it's happened? @TomJNowell

Answer (score 0):

the documentation that said there is the limit I got from this Post

[WP REST API returns blank response if post is too long](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317823/wp-rest-api-returns-blank-response-if-post-is-too-long/367486#367486)

and just I just solve it
So How to fix this? I made a custom API, and convert my data to JSON using json_encode by using the option.

Solution $json = json_encode($your_array, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)

return $json

by using that solution, you no need to echo the data.

Thanks for helping.